# Multithreaded unit test

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, mstest

I have a helper class that validates an XML based on its schema. There are some static methods/function in combination with instance method/functions and I want to test it for thread safety.

What is the best approach to test this helper with MSTest (VS2008) ?

Comment: In general this is possible, but if we arer going to discuss concrete technique - please share a code you want to test

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question, by why not launch multiple simultanious threads to manupulate your class(es) and trap all threading related exceptions before waiting for all threads to finish and then check for concurrency problems in the results?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to unit test threading issues is to predict problems and let your test specifically cause each situation. Unit tests should always produce the exact same result each time they run against the same code.

You may want to check out Microsoft CHESS (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/) if you do not have a specific problem to test.

Comment: Single tests agains the public methods/functions all pass. But this component failed in production (Biztalk -> Orchestrations). Some times the message was validation succesfully while the message was invalid and vica versa....

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of hard of doing this, since you can not be sure about how de OS will schedule the threads execution. You tests will most likely randomly fail.
If you can, change your design so you can reduce locks/other synchronization techniques and design for thread safety (for example, not using shared state).